# Unable to initialise SqlParameter

Tags: c#, sqlparameter

I have the following code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using OPN.SP_Services.Interface;
using wwa.EPR.Services;

namespace OPN.SP_Services
{
    public class TestService : UnitOfWork<ClearviewLocalContext>, ITestService
    {
        public TestService(IDataContext<ClearviewLocalContext> dataContext) : base(dataContext)
        {

        }

        public void test()
        {
            var param = new SqlParameter();
        }
    }
}

namespace OPN.SP_Services.Interface
{
    public interface ITestService
    {
        void test();
    }
}
```

Dependency config:

```
container.Register<ITestService, TestService>();
```

called like this:

```
_testService.test();
```

When I step through the code and reach this line:

```
            var param = new SqlParameter();
```

and inspect the variable, I see the following in my locals:

[image]

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to not add the parameter to an SQLcommand?

Comment: @FreekW. I am using IDataContext and am having this issue. I have tried all the solutions suggested, but none work and I am wondering if this is the cause of the issue so have separated it out.

Comment: It's normal for some properties of an object to show as Null Reference Exceptions in the locals window, because that's what would happen if your code accessed them.

Comment: @stuartd do you mean that this code will execute fine unless I try and access one of the null properties? If so, if you put that as the answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the properties in red are `internal` properties, that don't work unless certain preconditions have been met. Usually, you'd never see them or access them out-of-order, *precisely because* they are `internal`. They are not required to be as well-behaved as `public` properties. That said: it isn't unusual for `public` properties to throw exceptions when accessed in an invalid state.

Basically: nothing to worry about here; no problems; business as normal. This is not the cause of whatever problem you are seeing elsewhere.